# Monitor doesn't turn off after shutdown

Tags: power-management, shutdown, monitor

My monitor used to turn off after I shutdown my computer but now it doesn't. The PC is a desktop and I didn't change any BIOS or graphics card or power management settings. I use the latest proprietary nvidia driver. My GPU is a nvidia GTX 650 TI

Comment: Just to make sure, does unplugging your power supply to your PC make a difference? Also, does unplugging your monitor cable make a difference? Are you left with the final screen displayed or is it a blank screen?

Comment: Well unplugging the power makes a differences yes because it wont have any current so it will turn off,. It displays that "no signal" box that monitors display when they dont get any input feed from the selected source. My computer shuts down completely its just that ubuntu doesnt send the termination signal to my monitor (there is such a signal thats been send during shutdown I just dont know how to evoke it again)

Comment: There is no terminate signal message, I am trying to troubleshoot the issue, does unplugging the PC from the power supply make a difference, when you turn your PC off, there is still active components running, unplugging the PC will help determine if this is what is causing your issue, it is possible that the TV is just remaining active because there is a closed circuit attached to the cable, I want to rule this out

Comment: When the kernel shuts down it calls (among other things) for "device_shutdown" which I think includes the monitor too, if its not then the other step which is relevant to ACPI may have something to do with telling the monitor to shut_down... in any case there is no way that linux doesnt signal the monitor to shut down.. how could the monitor know when to close on its own without a human pushing a button? And  I did what you asked just out of curiosity and unplug ed the PSU of my computer and again the monitor displays without any interruption the "no signal" window.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but on a laptop. It's a B40-30, Lenovo model with integrated graphics (not discrete graphics, no proprietary graphics drivers).